# Expo-speech not working on some iOS devices

Tags: expo, text-to-speech

I'm using `expo-speech` in my app but the text is not read out in some iOS devices. 
From getting my friends to test it the results I have are:

Works:

- iPhone X. 13.3.1
- iPhone 10.
- iPhone X. 13.3.1
- iPhone 8 Plus. 13.3.1
- iPhone 7+. 13.1.2

Not working:

- iPhone Xs. 13.3.1
- iPhone 8. 13.4.1

It also works fine in every iOS simulator that Ive tried when developing locally.

Ive created a very simple repo (link below) to test it out with this code:

```
import React from 'react';
import * as Speech from "expo-speech";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  setInterval(()=>{
    Speech.speak(`I am a test`);
  }, 2000);

  return (
     <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

https://snack.expo.io/@jamesweblondon/sound-test

Using the Expo app to test it on an iPhone 8 13.4.1 it's also not working.

UPDATE: It turns out that it's silent mode that's causing this: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8235

The ideal solution would be to make the sound play anyway as YouTube etc does.

Second best would be to detect silent mode in iOS so I can at least notify the user that this feature won't work and how to fix it.

Comment: I think you are using client mode

Comment: i was facing same issue on my react-native app https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/workout-timer-custom-intervals/id1458958688 and in my app issue was slient mode

Comment: I was fixed by these two lines of code var Sound = require('react-native-sound');
Sound.setCategory('Playback'); it forcefully play sound in silent mode. but I was done in react-native, not an expo you can use the equivalent method in the expo

Comment: @MuhammadNuman yes it turns out it is silent mode that's the issue, which is unintuitive and YouTube etc still play. If I can detect this then at least I can notify the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing the same issue on my [workout-time](https://apps.apple.com/pk/app/workout-timer-custom-intervals/id1458958688) app because of silent mode.

## Expo Solution:

we can use [expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/audio/#arguments-1) expo library to play speech on slient mode by `playsInSilentModeIOS: true`

in expo text to speech is working when other sound is in playing mode. So you can attach empty sound

**download empty sound from** [**here**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/adoy9eit3ocu39a/soundFile.mp3?dl=0)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as Speech from "expo-speech";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Platform } from "react-native";
import { Audio } from "expo-av";
const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

export default function App() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const enableSound = async () => {
      if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
        await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
          playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
        });
        await soundObject.loadAsync(require("./soundFile.mp3"));
        await soundObject.playAsync();
      }

      setInterval(() => {
        Speech.speak(`I am a test`);
      }, 1000);
    };
    enableSound();
  });

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.tsx to start working on your app!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

## React-Native Solution:

```
var Sound = require('react-native-sound');

Sound.setCategory('Playback'); // this will enable sound on silent mode
```

Comment: I dont think you can have an async function directly within a useEffect hook?

Comment: yes, you are right we should not use async directly with useEffect. it just gave warning and working fine. I update my answer

Comment: This isn't working for me on my iPhone 8 13.4.1. Silent mode stops `I am a test` being read out.

Comment: Still not working. I tried triggering it from a button rather than useEffect but that also didnt work.

Comment: let me check it on my side

Comment: @Evanss yeah, you are right it is not playing speech on my side on the expo. let me think of playback sound solution for speech

Comment: strange, await soundObject.loadAsync(require("./soundFIle.mp3"));
        await soundObject.playAsync() mp3 is playing in silent mode but text to speech is not playing let me see native code of expo speech

Comment: I found the solution. play empty mp3 and then play text to speech. then text to speech is working on my side. I update answer

Comment: @Evanss I have updated my answer and attach empty sound. you can test it on your side

Comment: Ive had a new issue with Expo web where Safari errors, in dev mode this crashes the page. I think it doesn't like the page playing a sound before the user has interacted with it. Im just checking that triggering it from a button click (not on page load) works.

Comment: @Evanss we should playsound only for ios not for andorid and web. i have update my answer

Comment: Actually Safari on an iPhone has the same issue.

Comment: @Evanss I think we should detect silent mode and give alert to the user to off the silent mode only for the web. but unfortunately, there is not APi to detect silent mode

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215813/discussion-between-muhammad-numan-and-evanss).

Comment: I have left a message in chat